# How do I generate C# code from my UML models in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, uml, code-generation

I have modelled my application in UML using VS2010.

Now, how do I generate C# code from my UML models in VS2010?

Comment: found it (I think) here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795.aspx

Comment: The sad thing is that, out of the box, you cannot. This always got me wondering - why they spent all that effort supporting UML if it didn't work at launch. Oh, BTW, you might want to grab Feature Pack 2 for Visual Studio since IIRC that has _some_ support for code generation.

Comment: Correct, if you have an MSDN subscription, Visual Studio 2010 Feature Pack 2 lets you generate C# code from UML class diagrams.